# Is there a way to extract UserId and Password from a Connection String?

Tags: powershell, connection-string, azure-powershell

I have a connection string

```
Server=tcp:abcd.database.net;Initial Catalog=abcd;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=User123;Password=Password123;MultipleActiveResultSets=False
```

I would like to extract the User Id, and Password from this connection string. Do I have to use string manipulation and what would be the best way to do that OR is there a better way to get the UserId or Password

```
$conn=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "Vault" -Name "Secret" -AsPlainText
```

but the above only gives me an object with the basic properties.

Comment: `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert that's awesome, didn't know about it. I was going to propose `ConvertFrom-StringData`. Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: Because then I'd need to post more than one word. Left as an exercise to the reader. :)

Comment: Thankyou for sending me down that path. That definitely helped. However, when i do ```$connString=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnectionNew-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder($conn.ConnectionString)```, i get an error A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument

Comment: Try this: `[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder]$Server`

Comment: That worked! I realized that the new-object cmdlet that I was passing in had some garbage data which was causing the error

Comment: @Amy if you could solve the problem by yourself, you could post the answer to show others how you could solve it. It might help others in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I followed what @Jeroen Mostert pointed me to and read up on SqlConnectionStringBuilder and tried the below command that worked for me

```
$ConnectionString = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "KeyVault" -Name "secretname" -AsPlainText
$connString = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnectionStringBuilder($ConnectionString)
$sqlServerId = $connString["User ID"]
$sqlServerPwd = $connString["Password"]
```